# Ionic 5 app no longer builds after updating Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, cordova, ionic5

I have a Cordova (not Capacitor) Ionic 5 app which I have been working on for a while and built many times. To check something on another project; someone gave me a a project which required Capacitor to build. It seems Capacitor has no cli build function so I was required to upgrade Android Studio to build from there. That worked.

But now I can no longer build my original project. It does run fine in the browser however.

There are numerous pages of build errors but the most relevant samples seem to be these:

E:\www\sz.app\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\ionicframework\cordova\webview\IonicWebViewEngine.java:11: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
> E:\www\sz.app\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\com\ionicframework\cordova\webview\IonicWebViewEngine.java:137: error: cannot find symbol
> @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
> ^
> symbol:   class RequiresApi
> location: class IonicWebViewEngine.ServerClient

E:\www\sz.app\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\plugin\google\maps\PluginMap.java:192: error: cannot find symbol
boolean locationPermission = PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission(cordova.getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
^
symbol:   variable PermissionChecker
location: class PluginMap

E:\www\sz.app\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\plugin\google\maps\PluginLocationService.java:260: error: cannot find symbol
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult result) {
^
24 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 23 up-to-date
symbol: class NonNull

Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

## Ionic info:

Ionic:

Ionic CLI                     : 6.10.1 (C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@ionic\cli)
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.1.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.901.6
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 9.1.6
@angular/cli                  : 9.1.6
@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.2.0

Capacitor:

Capacitor CLI   : 2.1.0
@capacitor/core : 2.1.0

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : not installed
Cordova Platforms : not available
Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 9 other plugins)

Utility:

cordova-res                          : not installed
native-run (update available: 1.0.0) : 0.2.8

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\android-sdk)
NodeJS            : v12.18.2 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
npm               : 6.14.5
OS                : Windows 7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This type of error occurs when an Android project contains references to both the AndroidX (Jetifier) library and its deprecated predecessor, the Android Support Library.
In a Cordova project, this typically happens when some plugins have migrated to AndroidX and others are still using the Android Support Library.

First ensure AndroidX is enabled in your Cordova project.
Either make sure the Android platform is `cordova-android@9` or install [cordova-plugin-androidx](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-androidx) into a `cordova-android@8` project.

Then install [cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter) which will dynamically patch the source code of plugins to migrate from Android Support Library to AndroidX.
Note this currently only works for Java and XML source files (not Kotlin or compiled libraries e.g. JAR or AAR).

Comment: Awesome!! This worked perfectly. A couple comments: i didn't know what cordova-android@8 or @9 was; but i did cordova -v and it reported 9.0.0, so i assumed that was it. Which means i likely didn't need to install androidx plugin; but i already had it from debugging this earlier. The androidx-adapter was the key.

Comment: `cordova-android` refers to the Cordova Android platform version which you can obtain with `cordova platform ls`. `cordova -v` gives you the Cordova CLI version.

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks. In that case I have 8.1.0, so sounds like i would have needed androidx plugin; which i had/have.